# Incorrect Syntax Near @ThisDB

Tags: sql-server, variables

I am trying to change the schema of a DB, usually, I fix this by just replacing the variable with the DBs Name. However, I am trying to make this check what DB it's being run on by itself.

I have already run this on other DBs, and it works. However, for some reason, some DB's will throw following the ERROR.

> Syntax Error Near '@ThisDB'

```
--Set current DB as @ThisDB
DECLARE @ThisDB NVARCHAR(50)
SET @ThisDB = DB_NAME()
--Change Schema of @ThisDB
USE @ThisDB -- <= Error occurs here
DROP SCHEMA @ThisDB
DROP USER @ThisDB
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::@ThisDB TO @ThisDB
```

Honestly, I'm pretty sure the code here is right. Since I know it runs on other DB's.

My question is why this wouldn't run on some DB.

Answer (score 0):

The `USE` statement can only be followed by an identifier.  You can not put a variable after the `USE` statement.

[USE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017)

In general you can't just replace object identifiers with variables, so it also won't work with your drop and alter statements either.

You might have to use something like Dynamic SQL using `sp_executesql` or `EXEC` statements to accomplish what you want.

Comment: So if I am trying to run this from a direct query, not from say the master or TempDB query. Do I need USE?

Comment: Also, not to be an askhole, but can you briefly explain what Dynamic SQL is?

Comment: No problem :) If you look up sp_executesql or the EXEC statement you'll see how to send a string of text to the query engine.  You can build a string with the object names you want.  Just do an internet search for "Dynamic Sql".

Comment: @RedGrinGrumble check out the duplicate link I posted above, it shows you exactly how to do it.